# Swift ios textview in tableview cell not generated in correct size

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have cell and in that cell view with textview in it. On textview is border bottom with `EZSwiftExtensions`.

Now problem is that border is not full width on first load, but when i scroll down and scroll to top that border is full width.

Why is that happening?

When app loads:

[image]

When scroll down and come back to top:

[image]

Cell xcode:

[image]

Cell code:

```
import UIKit
import EZSwiftExtensions

class JokeTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    var item: Joke! {
        didSet {
            cellView.setCornerRadius(radius: 4)
            hearthImg.image = UIImage(named: "HearthWhite")
            starImg.image = UIImage(named: "StarWhite")
            txtLabel.addBorderBottom(size: 1, color: UIColor.lightGrayColor())
            setupCell()
        }
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var cellView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var authorLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var txtLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var hearthImg: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var likesLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var starImg: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var scoreLabel: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }

    func setupCell() {
        authorLabel.text = item.creator
        if item.creator == "" {
            authorLabel.text = "Aninomno"
        }
        txtLabel.text = item.text
        if item.liked == true {
            hearthImg.image = UIImage(named: "HearthRed")
        }
        if item.rated == true {
            starImg.image = UIImage(named: "StarYellow")
        }
        likesLabel.text = item.likes.toString
        scoreLabel.text = item.score.toString
    }

}
```

I need it to be full width always.

Comment: There are a few resons for which this could happen. Have you checked if the `textView` size is as expected before scrolling? If not use view debugger to check.

Comment: It is, i tested on long string, so it shows full width, but border still isn't full width.

Comment: My guess is that you use autolayout and the line is draw before the views are updated to reflect the constraints. I think it is a bug in the library you are using could you share more details (or some code) that you are using.

Comment: @MirzaDelic can you please check if category involves using core graphics or working on layer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation of the `addBorderBottom` is not that great. You could override `layoutSubviews` and use `addBorderBottom` there and it should work. However that method is called multiple times and you will end up having multiple borders stacked one over the other.
You could implement yourself a border, by using a `UIView` with height 1px as subview and some margin contraints, I think this is the easiest solution.